# How to access JSON object property from data returned by AJAX call?

Tags: json, ajax, object

I'm making an AJAX call to this php file:

```
<?php 
    $result = array('error' => "Please enter a valid name");
    echo  json_encode($result)
?>
```

In my javascript file, I have:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/controller/common/review_processing.php", 
    data:dataString, 
    success:function (data) {
        var returned_data = data;
        console.log(returned_data); <---This outputs {"error":"Please enter a valid name"} 
        console.log(returned_data.error); <---This outputs undefined
    }

});
```

My data seems to be encoded as a JSON object correctly but when I try to access a specific property, I get an undefined result.

What I want is for `console.log(returned_data.error)` to output:

> Please enter a valid name

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: However, you can also provide the `dataType: 'json'` option to `$.ajax` and jQuery will parse the response automatically for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try :

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/controller/common/review_processing.php", 
    data:dataString,
    dataType: "json", <--response itself will be handled as JSON
    success:function (data) {
        var returned_data = data;
        console.log(returned_data); <---This outputs {"error":"Please enter a valid name"} 
        console.log(returned_data.error); 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this...

```
$.map(data.d, function (item) {
  console.log(item.error);
});
```